# Jquery for picture gallery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, image-gallery

I have a few pictures for a product and I want the user to be able to click the thumbnail and then display the large picture.  I used the simple JQuery tutorial http://papermashup.com/simple-jquery-gallery/ , but for some reason, when I click on the thumbnails, only the large picture of the thumbnail I clicked on is display.  The other thumbnails disappeared so  I can't click back to it.

I am using Carrierwave, rails 3.2 and the jquery that comes with rails 3.2

```
$(function() {
$(".image").click(function() {
var image = $(this).attr("rel");
$('#image').hide();
$('#image').fadeIn('slow');
$('#image').html('<img src="' + image + '"/>');
return false;
});
});


<div id ="image" >
 <%= image_tag(@product.prod_images.first.image_url(:large_pic)) %>
 <% @prod_images.each do |image| %>          
 <ul class="thumbs">
  <li>
   <a href="#" rel="<%= image.image_url(:large_pic) %>" class="image">
     <%= image_tag(image.image_url(:thumb_pic)) if image.image? %>
   </a>
  </li>
 </ul>
 <% end %>
</div>
```

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set the HTML of #image, you replace all the code inside . that why your thumbnail tags disappeared .

You should try this instead :

```
 <div id ="image" >
     <%= image_tag(@product.prod_images.first.image_url(:large_pic)) %>
 </div>
<% @prod_images.each do |image| %>          
 <ul class="thumbs">
      <li>
       <a href="#" rel="<%= image.image_url(:large_pic) %>" class="image">
         <%= image_tag(image.image_url(:thumb_pic)) if image.image? %>
       </a>
      </li>
 </ul>
<% end %>
```

Comment: how would I go about making the thumbnail active?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use a lightbox gallery plugin, like [colorbox](http://jacklmoore.com/colorbox/)

Comment: Hi.  I am trying to avoid plugins because I don't know much jQuery and I don't want something full out.  I am currently using the Galleriffic plugin, but it's so complicated that I have to dance around it with my other code.

Answer (score 0):

You're div tag with the id of "image" contains your li.  In your script, you are replacing the HTML of that div with the image tag.  You should move your li out of the "image" div and into a separate div.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  Even though your answer is the same as MKal, since he put out the actual code.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The solution ended up being this:

```
$('#thumb_holder li a').click (function(){
        mainImg = $(this).attr('rel');
        if(mainImg != current){
            $('.current').fadeOut('slow');
            $('#'+mainImg).fadeIn('slow', function(){
                $(this).addClass('current');
                current = mainImg;
            });
            $('#thumb_holder li').find('img').css('display','block');
        }
        $(this).children("img").toggle();
    });
```